Can I use '+=' operator with EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS variable to add usermod commands from multiple files?
I'm using Yocto Kirkstone. To modify users on my embedded linux target device I use extrausers class along with EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS variable. At first I used it for changing root password.
So in my custom-image.bb file, in which I define my image, I was using:
inherit extrausers
#Change root password
PASSWD = "\$5\$2BF1ipFTZnZ0Kkp5\$O30hqNFAhq8GDIZb23XH7/JC3Z20sGiwrA1rSH3jzk9"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
  usermod -p '${PASSWD}' root; \
"

And that worked.
In the next step, I was trying to change another user configuration. It was www-data user, which is apache2 user on my target system. From apache2_%.bbappend file:
#----Modify user for apache2 - www-data user-----
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS += "\
    usermod -d /home/www-data/ www-data; \
    "

do_install:append(){
    install -d ${D}/home/www-data
}
FILES:${PN} += "/home/www-data"

I also changed the assign operator in my custom-image.bb file from = to +=, so that both assignments to EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS were using +=.
But it didn't work, the home directory of www-data user was installed, but the user configuration was not applied (usermod -d /home/www-data/ www-data; did not apply)
Why I can't use EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS from multiple files?
When I tried moving usermod -d /home/www-data/ www-data; to custom-image.bb, so to the same place where the root password is being changed, then it worked. My intention of configuring the www-data user from apache2 append file was to keep things clean and organized.

Someone had the same problem in 2021: https://github.com/lgirdk/poky/issues/1
You could try shifting the linked commits, but I think most/all are false positives.
What happens if you use += in both cases? Maybe the first recipe is overwriting the variable content of the second one. Apart from that your recipe looks fine to me

@Mo_ thanks for the link. I think the problem described there isn't completely the same, because I am not getting any error during the build. In my case, it just does only one extrausers action instead of two. I tried using += in both cases, it's the same.

Another idea: Use useradd bbclass. There's an example in poky/meta-skeleton.  I think you do not want extra_user, because the docs say: "This is a more global method of providing user and group configuration as compared to using the useradd class, which ties user and group configurations to a specific recipe".

I use useradd.bbclass in some of my recipes to add users, and it works fine. But the problem is that the user I want to modify: www-data, already exists (is default user in Poky). And I think that useradd.bbclass can only create, not modify users. Please correct me if I am wrong.

You can at least chown directories. Is that enough for your use case? If not, why?
